# How did the Purifiers know about Hope in Messiah Complex?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, messiah-complex

At the beginning of Messiah Complex, the Purifiers are already on the scene when Hope is born.

Later on we find out that The Reverend Stryker found out about it from a prophecy, which is not something I thought was possible for humans in Marvel.

How did the Purifiers know about Hope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In New X-Men Vol2 #36 (in a flashback 3 months before M-day), in the Facility, Purifiers’ leader Rev. William Stryker, while experimenting with Nimrod, tells facility scientist Adam Harkins that a supremely powerful mutant will be send (born) in the world months later.

Given that Nimrod comes from the future, it looks to me that Stryker has pulled data (forthcoming events) from the robot (Nimrod) and catalog them as prophecies.

[image]

Comment: I would be great to see the Rev. Getting that data from Nimrod on-panel but I also don't see that as likely to be shown. Great finds!